# UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextview

I have noticed a very weird behavior with `UITextView`.

When İ register for `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification`, the callback is invoked twice for every keystroke.

The delegate callback `textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` gets only called once correctly.

Has anyone noticed the same thing? I'm really just adding an observer to a default `UITextView`, and `YES`, in the callback I'm checking whether the `UITextView` that sent the notification is the one I created (I only have 1 in my test project).

For those of you who REALLY need some code for this :

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
[self.view addSubview:textView];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textDidChange:)
                                             name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

thats it.

textDidChange: is called twice on every keystroke.

**BIG EDIT**

I'm very very sorry for confusing you. I should have cleared out that I'm adding the UITextView itself as the observer.

The sample code is also wrong, sorry for that.

The correct sample code would be:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textDidChange:)
                                             name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
    }
}
```

Any guess why it is called twice, if I'm adding the textView itself as an observer for this notification ?

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: ok this is really THE simplest use of a textView. but sure, i added some 'sample code'

Comment: Using you simplest code, I get only one notification, so I guess there must be something else going on.

Comment: @lucianomarisi sorry for sounding rude, but that was pure frustration speaking :/

Comment: OK i can confirm that adding a different object (not the textView itself) as the observer solves this problem. But i'd really like to know why it is called twice when the textView is the observer

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, and regarding your code, if it´s in viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad, and you dealloc this UIViewController but "not" unregister the observer, it´s going to be active, and its a potential reason it´s being called for 2 times. Take a look and be sure you are removing the observer properly.
It can happen as well, you hide the view or whatever, and you add the observer everytime the view is visible and it can be a problem. I would recommend to register the events in viewDidAppear and dont forget to remove the observers in dealloc.

Comment: thank you for your response. i'm aware of removing observers. in this case, guess the problem is adding the textView itself as the observer

Answer (score 0):

Are you subclassing UITextView? If so, check if you are creating more than one instance of the class and therefore creating more than one observer.

Set a breakpoint in your init method of the UITextView subclass. If it gets hit more than once, then your textDidChange handler will get called that many times.

To fix, you can check for each instance of the UITextView in the handler method:

```
if let textView = notification.object as? MyTextViewSubClass where textView === self {
    print(textView.text)
}
```